# image not moving to uploads folder in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm uploading photos to a database. The image destination does appear in the database, however, when I go to my uploads folder, the images aren't there. The folder has both read and write permissions. I created two functions in my code. One is used to gather the information from the images (I am trying to upload 3 images at a time). The other one is used to compress the image and return the destination.

I then use that destination and insert it into my sql database table. The problem is that it does get uploaded into the database table, BUT when I go check the uploads folder, the images aren't there. Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
        // Set up variables based on the inputs from the form on upload-page.php
        $img1_name = $_FILES['img1']['name'];
        $img1_tmp = $_FILES['img1']['tmp_name'];

        $img2_name = $_FILES['img2']['name'];
        $img2_tmp = $_FILES['img2']['tmp_name'];

        $img3_name = $_FILES['img3']['name'];
        $img3_tmp = $_FILES['img3']['tmp_name'];

        // Variables to hold destination of compressed image
        $img1_comp = compressed($img1_name, $img1_tmp);
        $img2_comp = compressed($img2_name, $img2_tmp);
        $img3_comp = compressed($img3_name, $img3_tmp);

        // Insert values into the SQL Projects table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Projects(img1, img2, img3) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
            header("Location: ../upload-page.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        }
        else{
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $img1_comp, $img2_comp, $img3_comp);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            header("Location: ../upload-page.php?upload=success");
            exit();
        }
    }
    else{
        header("Location: ../upload-page.php");
        exit();
    }

    // Function that will gather file info and pass it to compressImage() function
    function compressed($img_name, $img_tmp){
        // File info 
        $uploadPath = "uploads/";
        $imageUploadPath = $uploadPath.$img_name; 
        $fileType = pathinfo($imageUploadPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
         
        // Allow certain file formats 
        $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg'); 
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
            // Compress size and upload image 
            $compressedImage = compressImage($img_tmp, $imageUploadPath, 75); 
             
            if($compressedImage){ 
                $compressedImageSize = filesize($compressedImage);
                move_uploaded_file($img_tmp, $compressedImage);
                return $compressedImage;    //Return the compressed image destination
            }else{ 
                $statusMsg = "Image compress failed!"; 
            } 
        }else{ 
            $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG & PNG files are allowed to upload.'; 
        }
    }

    // Function that will compress image and return destination
    function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) { 
        // Get image info 
        $imgInfo = getimagesize($source); 
        $mime = $imgInfo['mime']; 
         
        // Create a new image from file 
        switch($mime){ 
            case 'image/jpeg': 
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source); 
                break; 
            case 'image/png': 
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($source); 
                break; 
            case 'image/gif': 
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($source); 
                break; 
            default: 
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source); 
        } 
         
        // Save image 
        imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality); 
         
        // Return compressed image 
        return $destination; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before and what solved it for me was using the server root path

```
$uploadPath= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. This is weird because I've done this several times before and it's worked in the past.